# Real address of myetherwallet. How to know?

Tags: myetherwallet

I am going to use

https://myetherwallet.com/

However, is that the real address?

How do I know it's not phishing?

Any phissing site will be like that too right?

Comment: I need an answer that confirm that myetherwallet.com is indeed a right address

Comment: I confirm that address is correct. My answer was to show all of the ways you can protect yourself. The easiest way for the web address is to click on the SSL certificate in the URL bar (in Chrome it appears as "Secure") to make sure that it has one. But yes, that is the correct URL for MyEtherWallet.

Comment: Please add that to the answer.

Comment: Okay, I've just done that.

Comment: Just a quick comment: never take anyone's word that a particular site is the correct one, or that it's secure, especially someone you've never met or had contact with before, and even more so when money is involved. Understand your trust and threat models, and form an idea based on quorum from various sources (e.g. Reddit). (Also note that a site having a valid SSL cert just means that someone has bought a cert for that particular site, or got one for free from Let's Encrypt. It helps rule out things like MITM attacks, but not from you thinking you're on the correct site when you're not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm that address is correct.  The easiest way for the web address is to click on the SSL certificate in the URL bar (in Chrome it appears as "Secure") to make sure that it has one. But yes, that is the correct URL for MyEtherWallet.

[This is the list of suggestions for all account security directly from MyEtherWallet's "Help Section"](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/getting-started/protecting-yourself-and-your-funds.html). The other answer is correct as well that you should verify the SSL certificate, but that link looks fine to me.

> 1. Get yourself a Ledger or TREZOR Hardware wallet.
>      One of the safest & easiest ways to store your ETH, Tokens, ETC, BTC, and many other coins is via a Ledger Nano S or TREZOR. Both are hardware wallets. Both work with MyEtherWallet.com. And both cost less $100 ( < 0.1 ETH ).
>      Buy a Ledger Nano S.
>      Buy a TREZOR.
>      If you don't want one of these nifty devices, use cold storage for a majority of your savings. Please. Pretty please.
> 2. Bookmark your crypto sites.
>      Use those bookmarks and only those.
> 3. Install the EAL Chrome Extension or the MetaMask Chrome Extension to warn you if you go to a crypto-phishing link.
> 4. Use MEW Locally / Offline.
> 5. Do not trust messages or addresses or URLs sent via private message. Always verify information w/ a secondary source.
>      Don’t click any link regarding anything crypto, money, banking, or a service like Dropbox / Google Drive / Gmail in any email ever.
>      And if the scammy clickbait was simply too irresistible for you, don’t enter any information on the page.
>      Never enter your private keys, passwords, sensitive data on a website that you were sent via message
> 6. Turn on 2FA for everything.
>      Go do it. Right now. Quit your excuses. Choose Google Authenticator over Authy. Don't use your phone number. Then, make sure your phone number is NOT tied to your Google account (look in privacy settings). Turns out, you and your BFF Mr. Hacker can "recover" access to your account via that number, completely destroying the point of 2FA.
>      PS: MyEtherWallet is client-side, meaning 2FA won't do anything in our case. 2FA is for ensuring the security of your password on a server.
>      PSS: Don't forget to cold-storage your backup words for these 2FA things. It's a huge pain when your phone goes for a swim and your entire life is 2FA'd. ?
> 7. For Token Sales: do not trust any address except the one posted on the official site.
>      Bookmark the URL before the sale, get the address from the URL from your bookmark at time of purchase. Do not trust any other source (especially a random bot on Slack). PS: When are token sales going to start using ENS names?
> 8. Double check the URL & Triple check Github URLs.
>      Check it. Then, check it again right before entering any information. This is especially important for any sites that require usernames, passwords, email addresses, private keys, and any other personal information. SSL certs do not mean a site is trustworthy, just that they bought an SSL cert. Not sure about the correct URL? Cross reference Reddit, Twitter, Github, Slack and wherever else the project hangs out.
>      Github URLs are much easier to fake and much easier to miss. Instead of downloading from that random URL on reddit, seek out the URL on your own. Following the developers of these repos on Twitter, friending them on reddit (lol...but seriously it's nice because their name will be orange), or starring said repos on Github helps.
> 9. Always verify that the site you landed on is legit.
>      Especially if you are about to enter your private key or download an application. What is legit? A service that people have used for a decent period of time with good results. If the URL has been registered in the last week or the site "just launched", err on the side of caution and avoid it for a while.
> 10. Google the service name + "scam" or "reviews"
>       Scam sites rarely last long. Value real comments by real people over a random blog. Value a collection of information over a single source. Understand that legit services will likely have a mix of positive and negative reviews over a long period of time. Scam sites typically have no one talking about them, everyone yelling about how they got robbed, or the most perfect reviews ever. The latter one is just as red of a flag as the first one.
> 11. Don't ever run remote-access software (e.g. TeamViewer)
>       Don't ever...but especially not on a computer with keys on them. The number of security holes in these programs is atrocious. You 2FA your entire life, but then let a single string of characters give someone access to your entire computer & every account. ?
> 12. Don't use brain wallets
>       Brain wallets are wallets where the key is derived from a word or phrase you choose. Human brains don't have the ability to create high-entropy seeds. Using a phrase that you make up, even if it seems "rare" or "random" is not as secure as using MyEtherWallet's randomness and these phrases can be bruteforced by the millions.  Read more. And more.
> 13. Install an adblocker that actually turns off Google/Bing Ads.
>       I recommend going with uBlock Orgin. If you are already using Adblock Plus, it does not hide Google Ads from you. Go into your Adblock Plus settings and uncheck the box that says “Allow some non-intrusive advertising”.
> 14. Don’t click on advertisements.
>       With or without an adblocker, you should never, ever click on advertisements.
> 15. If you have accidentally visited or typed a malicious site, clean out your recent history and autocomplete.
>       This will prevent you from typing kra… and having it autocomplete to the malicious krakken.com.
> 16. No one is giving you free or discounted ETH.
>       Even for completing a survey. ;)
> 17. The guys who just finish their token sale don't want to sell you tokens via Slack DM.
>       Neither does that smokin' hot 125px x 125px avatar.
> 18. Download the MEW Chrome Extension.
> 19. ONLY unlock your wallet when you want to send a transaction. Check your balance via https://etherscan.io/ , https://ethplorer.io/
> 20. Lastly: use your brain

Answer (score 0):

That does look like the real address. You can verify the SSL certificate by looking at the url bar and seeing if it shows as secure (usually a lock sign to the left of the url). Alternatively you can go to the myetherwallet github and download the official source code and run it locally.